# Como darle update a una base de datos MySQL usando php y Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una pagina como la que esta arriba. Se supone que si le doy new, en la parte superiori a la izq, me deje crear un usuario nuevo con su nombre, telefono, email, etc. Si le doy al zafacon me debe borrar la linea completa de mi pagina y mi base de datos. Si le doy al lapiz sale algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la pantalla me deje editar lo que ya tengo escrito. Al cambiar algo y darle al boton de Actualizar no se actualiza en mi base de dato y tampoco en la pagina. Como podria resolver este problema?? Estos son los codigos que tengo para darle update:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    
<head>

</head>
    
<body style="margin: 20px">
    
  
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "contactos";

$email = $_POST['ult'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "select * from USER " .
    " where email = '" . $email . "'";

    
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
//name, telefono, email, Dia, Mes, UltimoCelebrado
        $nombre = $row['name'];
        $tel = $row['telefono'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $dia = $row['Dia'];
        $mes = $row['Mes'];
        $ult = $row['UltimoCelebrado'];
      
    }
}
$conn->close();
?> 
    <form action= "demofinalUP2.php" method="post">
        <label>Nombre:</label>
        <input type='text' id='nombre' value='<?php echo $nombre ?>'><br>
        <label>Telefono:</label>
        <input type='text' id='tel' value='<?php echo $tel ?>'><br>        
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type='text' id='email' value='<?php echo $email ?>'><br>   
        <label>Dia:</label>
        <input type='text' id='dia' value='<?php echo $dia ?>'><br> 
        <label>Mes:</label>
        <input type='text' id='mes' value='<?php echo $mes ?>'><br> 
         <label>Ultimo Celebrado:</label>
        <input type='text' id='ult' value='<?php echo $ult ?>' readonly><br> <br>          
        
        <button type='button' id= 'updateRec'>Actualizar</button>
    </form>
 
    
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "contactos";
 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dia = $_POST['Dia'];
$mes = $_POST['Mes'];
$ultcel = $_POST['UltimoCelebrado'];

$sql = "UPDATE user " .
     "SET name = '" . $name . "'," .
     "telefono = '" . $tel . "'," .
     "email = '" . $email . "'," .
     "Dia = '" . $dia . "'," .
     "Mes = '" . $mes . "'," .
    "WHERE UltimoCelebrado = '" . $ult . "'";
 
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record was updated";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Estos son los de Javascript:

```js
$(document).on("click","#editRec", function () {
    var clickedItem = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
     $('#edit-window').css('visibility','visible');
 
    $.post("demofinalUP.php",
           { ult: clickedItem.find("#email").html() })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $('#forma-edit').html(data);
    });
   
});


$(document).on("click","#updateRec", function () {
   
     $('#edit-window').css('visibility','hidden');
    
    $.post( "demofinalUP2.php",
           { 
        "name" : $('#nombre').val(),
        "telefono" : $('#tel').val(),        
        "email" :  $('#email').val(),
        "Dia" :  $('#dia').val(),        
        "Mes" :  $('#mes').val(),     
        "UltimoCelebrado" :  $('#ult').val(),  
        
//           UltimoCelebrado: $('#ult').val(), 
//           name: $('#nombre').val(),
//           telefono: $('#tel').val(),
//           email: $('#email').val(),
//           Dia: $('#dia').val(),
//           Mes: $('#mes').val(),
           })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $('#forma-edit').html(data);
    });
   
});
```

Me falta algo? tengo algo mal? Me ayudarian un monton.

Comment: Qué errores aparecen en la consola y en 'Network'

Comment: Shaz gracias por contestar. Yo estoy usando Bracket para editar mi codigo, pero no aparece ningun error. Ni en la pag ni en Bracket. Si me debe de salir un error en donde lo puedo encontrar?

Comment: En Chrome. Es UltimoCelebrado la llave primaria?

Comment: Este código puede sufrir ataques de inyección de SQL. Usar MySQLi/PDO  es un buen paso para evitarlo, pero no es suficiente. También deberías usar consultas preparadas/parametrizadas en lugar de utilizar SQL dinámicas

Comment: Por cierto, ese UPDATE es un poco raro: si actualizas Luis Rodz (último celebrado: 2015) también se actualizaría el valor para Joe Smith (último celebrado: 2015)

Comment: La llave primaria es email ya que me pasaria lo que Alvaro dice que me actualizaria todos los que tuvieran el mismo año.

Comment: Pero el UPDATE tiene `"WHERE UltimoCelebrado = '" . $ult . "'"` por lo que no estás actualizando por email sino por el año de último celebrado y se actualizarían más de un registro con los mismos datos, ¿no?

Comment: Esa la cosa que nunca hace el Update a ninguna.

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra en `$('#forma-edit').html(data)` en el `done`?

Comment: Si yo corro el codigo desde la pagina web no me muestra nada, osea yo le doy al lapiz, me sale la pantalla para editar los dato que ya tengo al darle actualizar la pantalla desaparece y no hay cambios y no me sale en la parte de abajo "Record was updated".

Comment: ¿Y si abres la consola de JavaScript te sale algún error?

Comment: No me sale ningun error abrindo la consola. Se queda en blanco

Comment: Si vas a la pestaña de "Network" como sugiere Shaz, ¿aparece la llamada al PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Hermano hasta donde se no puede pasar por valor los datos suministrados directamente del php al html que es lo que tienes actualmente en el código, ese es un proceso que incluiria ajax pero te doy una solución muy practica y ve si te conviene.

Te sugiero que uses variables de tipo sesion de manera que cuando le des al boton actualizar éste si te tomaria el valor contenido de $ult. de manera que el ejemplo seria el siguiente...

En la pagina 1

```
    <?php
       session_start();
           .
           .
           //tu codigo aqui
           $_session['s_ult'] = $ult; // aqui es donde le asignas el valor
           .
           . 
    ?>
```

Ahora en la pagina donde ejecutas el codigo UPDATE

```
    <?php
       session_start();
           .
           .
           //tu codigo aqui
           $ult = $_session['s_ult']; // aqui es donde obtienes el valor de ult
                                   // de la pagina anterior
           .
           . 
    ?>
```

Así es como lo he usado yo y te puedo asegurar que funciona, pruebalo y nos avisa que tal te fue.

Comment: El codigo que tengo escrito lo dejo como esta y cambio lo que dice "$email = $_POST['ult'];" por ese codigo de session?

Comment: No sólo esto no responde a la pregunta, sino que además es incorrecto (de PHP a HTML no hace falta AJAX, es al revés; además OP está ya usando AJAX para eso cuando hace `$.post`). Y eso sin tener en cuenta que puede haber múltiples valores que pueden cambiar, ¿cuál se guardaría en la sesión?

Comment: seria algo como esto

        <?php
               session_start();
               .
               .
               // todo tu codigo como lo tienes
               $email = $_POST['ult'];
               $_session['s_ult'] = $_POST['ult'];
        ?>

Y para la pagina del UPDATE como te explique arriba, todo tu codigo queda igual.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dia = $_POST['Dia'];
$mes = $_POST['Mes'];

> $ultcel = $_POST['UltimoCelebrado'];

$sql = "UPDATE user " .
     "SET name = '" . $name . "'," .
     "telefono = '" . $tel . "'," .
     "email = '" . $email . "'," .
     "Dia = '" . $dia . "'," .
     "Mes = '" . $mes . "'," .
    "WHERE UltimoCelebrado = '" . $ult . "'";
```

En vez de `WHERE UltimoCelebrado='".$ult."'` deberia ser:

`WHERE UltimoCelebrado='".$ultcel."'` que es la variable que declaraste para recibir `$_POST['UltimoCelebrado']`